# How to Remote desktop connection from home to work in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

How to Remote desktop connection from home to work in windows 7.I can remote desktop connection LAN network.But i can't access from home to work.What is RD gateway and how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot setup a remote desktop connection from your home to work. You need to setup a **VPN**. Here's what you need to do:

1. Ensure that your work network administrator allows VPN.
2. Then u need to setup a VPN connection.
3. Check this link. http://compnetworking.about.com/od/vpn/ht/newvpnwindowsxp.htm
   It gives detailed instructions on how to setup a VPN connection.

Comment: +1 without the help/permission from the network administrator you could get in a lot of trouble setting up your own remote desktop setup to get around what they have in place. To answer the original question RD Gateway must be set up by your network administrator. Go ask them what you need to get remote desktop set it up, if you are even allowed to.

Answer (score 1):

Ok tnx.But i read following from windows help.

```
An RD Gateway server provides these benefits:

Enables Remote Desktop connections to a corporate network from the Internet without having to set up virtual private network (VPN) connections.

Enables connections to remote computers across firewalls.

Allows you to share a network connection with other programs running on your computer. This enables you to use your ISP connection instead of your corporate network to send and receive data over the remote connection.
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your home machine onto the VPN of your workplace.  You can then RDP as if you were at work.

Comment: Many IT departments would frown upon this.

Answer (score 0):

We didn't have to put the work machine on any vpn, although that is probably the safest/most secure way to do it.  If I remember right, we have a router with an external IP address.  We had to configure that router to forward traffic from a specific port to my machine's internal IP address.  That meant that my machine had to have a static IP.  I had to change some things in the registry to get RD to listen on the non-default port. So from home I used something like

EX.TE.NA.LIP:3191 to access my work machine via remote desktop.

Sorry I don't have any more specifics.  "the network guy" in the office set it all up for me.

Answer (score 0):

To setup a VPN, you may either already have a router that offers it, along with a cheap or free client software, or you may use a pure software-based solution. For the latter, see for example, the answers [here](https://superuser.com/questions/289928/hamachi-alternative-for-personal-server/299312#299312).